# Does Scala offer functionality similar to Pretty Print in Python?

Tags: scala, pprint

Does Scala offer functionality similar to Pretty Print `pprint` in Python?

Comment: What does PPrint in Python do? Can you explain?

Comment: Start here: http://erikengbrecht.blogspot.com/2010/12/easier-object-inspection-in-scala-repl.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Except for XML, that is -- there's a pretty printer for that, which generates interpreter-readable data.

In fact, it doesn't even have a way to print interpreter-readable data, mainly because of how strings are represented when converted to string. For instance, `List("abc").toString` is `List(abc)`.

Add to that, there's no facility at all that will break them based on width, or ident nested collections.

That said, it is doable, within the same limits as `pprint`.